# Google Sheets API / PHP - How do use A1 Notation to grab non-contiguous columns from sheet

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api

I have the Sheets api up and running.  I can pull my sheet in just fine.

However this sheet has a ton of columns and I only need a handful.

My current working code:

```
$range = 'LPs Input!A:O';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
```

What I want to do:

```
$range = 'LPs Input!C:D,O:P';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
```

But when I run this I get:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Unable to parse range: LPs Input!C:D,O:P",
"errors": [
{
  "message": "Unable to parse range: LPs Input!C:D,O:P",
  "domain": "global",
  "reason": "badRequest"
}
],
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}
```

As best I can tell this is valid A1 Notation.  How can I get specific columns from this sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Input!C:D,O:P` isn't valid A1 notation. From that statement it looks like you're trying to select multiple ranges in a single statement (Columns C to D and O to P).

There are a couple of ways you could tackle this:

- Select the entire range `Input!C:P` and just select the components that you need from the response
- Make two calls to the Google Sheets API using `Input!C:D` and `Input!O:P` to select the specific columns that you need. In this case I would also consider making a batch call to the Sheets API using the [spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet) method (there is a PHP example at the bottom of this page)
- Look at moving the O and P columns in the Sheet so that they sit in the E and F columns. You could then select these 4 columns using `Input!C:F`

For more information on A1 notation in Sheets see the following link:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation